# How to start Jenkins build remotely with cloudbees authentication enabled

Tags: jenkins, cloudbees

How to start Jenkins build remotely with cloudbees authentication enabled?

Please let me know the command to start it from a script or throw commang like wget/curl

Comment: Please show what research you have already done and what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can `POST` to `https://accountname.ci.cloudbees.com/job/jobname/build` passing your CloudBees username (typically an email address) and Jenkins API token (see `/me/configure`) for `BASIC` authentication.

But if you would rather not keep your full credentials in a script, you can pick an arbitrary token and configure that in the job definition, in which case `POST`ing to `build?token=…` without authentication will schedule a build. In the usual case that your Jenkins instance is not visible to anonymous users, this will not work (since the whole URL space is blocked), in which case the [Build Token Root plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin) may be used to accomplish the same thing.